# Please identify the set or sets, grey 6 x 6 circle and dark red and white curve with vent

Tags: set-identification

I have these two assemblies which I have no idea if they are from the same set or not. The black square on the round assembly can spin.  Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The build on the left is from [60002 - Fire Truck](https://brickset.com/sets/60002-1/Fire-Truck) - it's the turntable/mount for the ladder:

[image: Fire truck detail]
Based on containing the "Plate 6x6 round", and "Bottom W.Turntable 4x4"

The build on the right is from [60147 - Fishing Boat](https://brickset.com/sets/60147-1/Fishing-Boat) - it's one of the engines:

[image: Fishing boat detail]
It's currently the only set with "Plate W. Bows 2X3½" in New Dark Red.

Comment: @pete No worries - I've found the second one too.

Answer (score 5):

The parts on the right are from [60147-1: Fishing Boat](https://brickset.com/sets/60147-1/Fishing-Boat)
[image]

Based on the [Dark Red Brick, Modified 2 x 3 x 2/3 Two Studs, Wing End](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47456&colorID=59&in=A)
and the [White Wedge 4 x 3 Open with Cutout and 4 Studs](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47755&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I am missing one.  I will work it out with steering as needed.